# (Unity) Firebase doesn't work on Android build

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

It works fine on editor (on Android selected as platform) and on Windows build, but it can't access Firebase when I build it and play on my phone.

Error log:

2021/06/16 22:18:42.608 24966 25006 Error Unity DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'FirebaseCppApp-7_2_0': The specified module could not be found.

I had the exact same problem on Windows build, and I fixed it by building my project on x86_64 instead of x86. So I suspect it has something to do with the build, the installation or the "Select platforms for plugin" section on the plugin files.

Under Assets/Firebase/Plugins, I have some files with Android selected as platform, and 2 folders:

- iOS
- x86_64

I have no Android folder, I don't know if it is supposed to be that way.

I have tried reinstalling Firebase both as assets and using Package Manager and installing them in the correct order, following these steps:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup-alternative
All packages are the same version.

Also I have tried building the project on Mono and on IL2CPP, and tried the solutions on this thread: [Unity integrated with firebase works on Unity Editor but not on mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66751770/unity-integrated-with-firebase-works-on-unity-editor-but-not-on-mobile-device)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Solved!

Edit > Project Settings > Player > Target architectures:
Disabled ARMv7 and enabled ARM64 (Update: no need to disable ARMv7)

Then Assets > External Dependency Manager > Android Resolver > Force Resolve

Comment: You shouldn't need to disable Armv7 (although it will speed up builds when testing). Enabling arm64 is probably enough.

Comment: @PatrickMartin Exactly, just tried it and it works with both options enabled. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it worked for FirebaseCppApp-11_1_0 (Firebase version 11.1.0)
But not for FirebaseCppApp-11_2_0 (Firebase version 11.2.0)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).