# Why does Firebase Not Work on PICO 4 Headset even though it works in Unity Editor?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am attempting to get Firebase working inside a PICO 4 headset but I'm encountering the pictured error.

[image: Error]

It looks like it cannot load the DLL FirebaseCppApp_11_4_0 but I'm not sure what the issue could be. Any insights here that could help me in the right direction? Thank you!

Also, I have confirmed the file it's referencing is in the Firebase Assets folder:

[Assets/Firebase/FirebaseCppApp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8psFl.png)

Code for INIT:

```
Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
{
    var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
    if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
    {
        // Create and hold a reference to your FirebaseApp,
        // where app is a Firebase.FirebaseApp property of your application class.
        app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;
        auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance;

        // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
        dbReference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

        FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.EventLogin);
        // Set a flag here to indicate whether Firebase is ready to use by your app.
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
          "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
    }
});

Debug.Log("Completed Init");
FirebaseConnectionStatusText.text = "Connected";
```

I followed the Firebase tutorials for connecting and the weird thing is, it works perfectly in the Unity editor. Data will load from and save in Firebase but the second I build to the VR headset, it fails.

---

**UPDATE**

Based on comments received, I've attempted to update the FirebaseCppApp-11_4_0 plugin in the x86_64 folder to use Android but same error persists. I've tried restarting Unity and building again but still, same error.

[Image of Updating the CppApp plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F29NV.png)

Also, I am currently targeting ARM64 in my build so that *shouldn't* be the problem. Anything additional?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the correct platforms selected in the inspector for the plugin files? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginInspector.html

Comment: @RetiredNinja I updated the plugins to include Android but still the same error. See the updated post. Any other suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pico_4 the Pico 4 is an ARM64 chip. You need the plugin for that platform.

Comment: Not sure if that's helpful, you can see this answer about enabling ARM64 in target architecture https://stackoverflow.com/a/68010101/8581245