# Unity Firebase RTDB doesn't work after building

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Unity version 2020.3.22f1,
Firebase SDK 9.0.0 dotnet4

I've imported both the analytics and real-time database SDK.
The Analytics works perfectly fine.

Regarding the database, building an Android app bundle and uploading to internal test or building an APK and uploading directly to my phone or building for IOS and uploading to test-flight all 3 results with an error.

This is how I initialize Firebase-

```cs
FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
    //init analytics
    FirebaseAnalytics.SetAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);

    DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
    Debug.Log(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(DatabaseReference.Database.App.Options));
});
```

This is how I use the database (increment the win field of a specific level) -

```cs
DatabaseReference.Child("Levels").Child($"Level{levelNum}").Child("Wins").RunTransaction((mutableData) =>
{
    mutableData.Value = Int32.Parse(mutableData.Value.ToString()) + 1;
    return TransactionResult.Success(mutableData);
});
```

Referring to the log above in the `DatabaseRefrence` initialization, in the editor, I can see all the configuration properties - databaseUrl,apikey,AppId, etc...

Debugging the APK on my phone the Options property only includes the databaseUrl.
And when trying to perform a transaction to the database an error is being thrown -

```
W/Unity: Exception in transaction delegate, aborting transaction
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at ....(Firebase.Database.MutableData mutableData)
```

Things I've tried so far-

1. I've added the SHA1/SHA256 of both my debug Keystore and googles console App integrity
2. I've checked and the XML files are being generated with all the details successfully at the `streamingAssets` folder and at `Assets\Plugins\Android\FirebaseApp.androidlib\res\values\google-services.xml`
3. I've tried Initializing the Firebase app manually as mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/66874818/7210967, doing that indeed results with the debug.log above to include all the Options parameters but the same error occurs as if it doesn't actually use it. (I've tried doing that both with the configuration files in place and removed them completely).
4. I've tried overriding the default app instance Options.

I've read some posts saying that Proguard obfuscation might cause errors with firebase? couldn't find anything related to Unity.

If anyone has any ideas, please share! ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions in Firebase Realtime Database work a bit differently than you might expect, as they immediately invoke you handler with the client's guess about the current value of the node, which in general is going to be `null`.

So when you call `mutableData.Value` in your code, you get back `null` and you then call `ToString()` on it, which leads to the error you get. To solve this, first check whether the `mutableData.Value` is `null` before invoking methods on it.

```
int current = mutableData.Value is null ? 0 : Int32.Parse(mutableData.Value.ToString());
mutableData.Value = current + 1;
return TransactionResult.Success(mutableData);
```

*Syntax errors are possible in the above, as it's been a while since I wrote C#.*

---

A transaction send both the SDKs guess and your new value based on that guess to the server, which then does a compare-and-set operation. If the guess doesn't match the actual value in the database, the server rejects the write with the current value, which the client then uses to call your transaction handler again with an updated current guess.

Comment: Any reason for such behavior to only and consistently be presented after building but never in the editor?
Testing and reporting back in a few, ty!
btw - using your logic above, because of how transactions work in rtdb when the mutable data returns null, wouldn't it override it with a wrong value as I continue with the transaction

Comment: It works! yet the debug.log of the app options still only includes the databaseUrl, so how does it even work ? lol
ty!

Comment: I added a bit more explanation to my answer of how transactions work.